# Opscenter not loading. Life cycle manager not connecting to the cluster.

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter, bigdata

My opscenter always gets stuck with *Loading OpsCenter...* BTW this is my first installation and so far I did not get OpsCenter to run.

All three of these run normally.

```
nodetool status
service dse
service datastax-agent
```

I could reproduce it on both GChrome & MFirefox. Both remotely & running on localhost.

**opscenterd.log :**

```
2017-04-12 15:20:15,877 [myclustername]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['10.35.21.207'] Message: HTTP request http://10.35.21.207:61621/connection-status? failed: 
An error occurred while connecting: 107: Transport endpoint is not connected. (MainThread)
```

when using life cycle manager , it sees my cluster name I picked but could not connect. Here's what the log looks like when I attempt to start managing the un-managed cluster.

```
[opscenterd] ERROR: Problem while calling ImportClusterIntoLifecycleManagerController (AgentCommunicationFailure): Cluster Import Failure: Unable to determine the DSE version for the specified cluster.  Please verify that the Agents for this cluster are properly communicating with Opscenter.
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1122, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

 File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

 File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 2598, in ImportClusterIntoLifecycleManagerController
```

Comment: Have you checked against this? https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/online_help/opscModifyingClusterSetting_t.html

Comment: You'd need to post more info to get meaningful help. I'm guessing you have a firewall or security-group problem. Have a look at https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/reference/opscLcmPorts.html

Also, as an aside... if you can't get the OpsCenter UI to load, how are you doing the LCM import? I think there must be some steps missing in your question.

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek I did this seems like a different issue. Checked the browser console etc. 
 Not a firewall or port issue, I'm sure there are no firewalls & I tested it locally on the server where opscenter is installed. 
I go directly to LCM via :8888/opscenter/lcm.html this hyperlink since I know that this is where LCM is. 
I will keep you posted.